# Syntax Error for elif in python for basic calculator

Tags: python

I am new to coding and I just learned python. May someone tell me what is wrong with this code?

error:
elif op == "-":
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Main codes:

```
print("Basic caculator")
num1 = float(input("Enter the first number: "))
op = input("Seclect an operator among +, -, *, /")
num2 = float(input("Enter the second number: "))

if op == "+":
    print("The result is " + str(num1 + num2)
elif op == "-":
    if num1 > num2:
        print("The result is " + str(num1 - num2)
    else:
        print("The result is " + str(num2 - num1)
elif op == "*":
    print("The result is " + str(num1 * num2)
elif op == "/":
    print("The result is " + str(num1 / num2)
    if num1 == 0 and num2 == 0:
        print("It is undefined")
    if num2 == 0:
        print(num1 + " cannot be divided by " + num2)
else:
    print("Invalid operator")
```

Comment: You're not closing your print statements, e.g. `print("The result is " + str(num1 + num2))`. You need two parenthesis at the end; one to close the `str` call and another for `print`

Answer (score 2):

You are missing the closing parentheses on your function calls.

It should be: `print("The result is " + str(num1 + num2))`
You have a similar problem in subsequent lines.